# How to check if first character in a Python dataframe column is a digit

Tags: python, dataframe

I have some address information in a Python dataframe, and I would like to check if the first character of one of the columns is a digit. I've found similar queries but nothing within a dataframe. I can extract the first character no problem using:

```
check = df['ADDRESS_LINE_1'].str[0]
```

however if I try

```
check = df['ADDRESS_LINE_1'].str[0].isdigit()
```

I get the error

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

I can't find an equivalent code to get this to work in a dataframe. I've also tried creating a new column with the check information in, but this results in the same error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to chain another `str`:

```
check = df['ADDRESS_LINE_1'].str[0].str.isdigit()
                                   #^ here
```

Example:

```
In [127]:
s = pd.Series(['3asd', 'asd', '3423', 'a123'])
s.str[0].str.isdigit()

Out[127]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

You can use a regex to specifically target whether the first character is numerical:

```
In [128]:
s.str.match('^\d')

Out[128]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

The error is telling you that `isdigit` isn't a method for `Series`, [`str.isdigit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html) is

Answer (score 0):

Another option, you can use `str.match` which matches a regex from the beginning of a string:

```
df
#     A
#0  2sdf
#1  sd3
#2  sss
#3  45q

df.A.str.match("\d")

#0     True
#1    False
#2    False
#3     True
#Name: A, dtype: bool
```